# How to create directories recursively in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to store a file as /a/b/c/d.txt, but I do not know if any of these directories exist and need to recursively create them if necessary.
How can one do this in ruby?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Use [`mkdir_p`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir_p):

```
FileUtils.mkdir_p '/a/b/c'
```

The `_p` is a unix holdover for parent/path you can also use the alias [`mkpath`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir) if that makes more sense for you.

```
FileUtils.mkpath '/a/b/c'
```

In Ruby 1.9 FileUtils was removed from the core, so you'll have to `require 'fileutils'`.

Comment: +1. `FileUtils` and `Pathname` are probably *the* most important tools for Ruby shell scripting.

Answer (score 23):

Use mkdir_p to create directory recursively

```
path = "/tmp/a/b/c"

FileUtils.mkdir_p(path) unless File.exists?(path)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are running on unixy machines, don't forget you can always run a shell command under ruby by placing it in backticks.

```
`mkdir -p /a/b/c`
```

Comment: Being so positive is though.

Comment: Poping system command into sub-process is not the best idea. It's better to do it with the Ruby standard library to get error handling, check the result, etc.

Answer (score 5):

[Pathname](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) to the rescue!

```
Pathname('/a/b/c/d.txt').dirname.mkpath
```

Comment: This is less intuitive than the accepted answer. Also the doc for the method forward to FileUtils https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-mkpath

Comment: The question is: "I want to store a file as /a/b/c/d.txt, but I do not know if any of these directories exist". My solution allows to use the existing file path ('/a/b/c/d.txt'), and, without separate parsing, create all the folders.

Comment: You mean this allow to do `FileUtils.mkdir_p '/a/b/c'` + create  `d.txt` at the same time?

Comment: Nope, instead it allows `Pathname('/a/b/c/d.txt').dirname.mkpath` and `File.write('/a/b/c/d.txt', content)` without `filename = '/a/b/c/d.txt'.rpartition('/').last` and the rest of the parsing

Answer (score 3):

```
 require 'ftools'
```

[File.makedirs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M002586)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! The docs seem to prefer FileUtils.mkdir_p, so I took that...

Comment: This is only an alias for `mkdir_p` and `mkpath` https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir_p

Answer (score 0):

You could also use your own logic

```
def self.create_dir_if_not_exists(path)
  recursive = path.split('/')
  directory = ''
  recursive.each do |sub_directory|
    directory += sub_directory + '/'
    Dir.mkdir(directory) unless (File.directory? directory)
  end
end
```

So if path is 'tmp/a/b/c'
if 'tmp' doesn't exist 'tmp' gets created, then 'tmp/a/' and so on and so forth.

Comment: One would avoid to reinvent the wheel.