# Does Ruby have mkdir -p?

Tags: ruby, file, path, directory, mkdir

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create directories recursively in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686032/how-to-create-directories-recursively-in-ruby)

In Ruby, how could I do:

```
mkdir -p cool/beans
```

1. Here's what I came up with:

   ```
   Dir.mkdir('cool') unless File.directory?('cool')
   cool_beans_path = File.join('cool', 'beans')
   Dir.mkdir(cool_beans_path) unless File.directory?(cool_beans_path)
   ```

   But, isn't there a better way?
2. I know I could do:

   ```
   system('mkdir', '-p', File.join('cool', 'beans'))
   ```

   But, that's not platform independent, is it? Like, it works on Mac but not on Windows, right?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.mkdir_p 'cool/beans'
```

Comment: Note: Tilda is not automatically expanded.

Comment: Docs: [`FileUtils.mkdir_p`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir_p)

Comment: Is there any way to make a recursive temporary directory, other than first creating a tmpdfir and then doing a Dir.mkdir inside the temporary directory?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.