# ruby and mingw32 - path issues

Tags: ruby, mingw

I am trying to run a simple ruby script on windows using mingw32

I am having some path issues I think because the simple script below uses the windows mkdir instead of the mkdir that ships with mingw32. I know this because it creates two files "-p" and "hello" which is what the windows mkdir does.  It is supposed to just create the hello direcory. -p is a switch.  The mkdir command works fine on the ming32 prompt.  How do I make ruby use the right mkdir?

mkdir.rb:

`mkdir -p hello`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Ruby have mkdir -p?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463343/does-ruby-have-mkdir-p)

Comment: not really, I am asking how to invoke mingw32's mkdir from ruby

Comment: Do you **need** to call `mkdir` using backticks? Why can't you use the `mkdir_p` provided by Ruby? That should do the appropriate thing for your platform.

Comment: that would probably be better but I inherited this script.  Switched to cygwin and script works perfectly