# Create subdirectories in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to create a sub-directory of a directory that does not exist like: `/foo/bar`

I tried:

```
Dir.mkdir("foo/bar")
```

but this does not work.

Comment: Seems pretty clear what the question is here, and it has quite a clear answer.  Closing it seems a bit OTT.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686032/how-to-create-directories-recursively-in-ruby

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are trying to create a directory and its parent directories, you want to use [`FileUtils.mkdir_p`](http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/classes/FileUtils.html#M000711) instead.

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.mkpath('/foo/bar')
```

`mkpath` is an alias of `mkdir_p`.