# How to create a directory with a slash '/' in its name

Tags: ruby

For example, I want to create a folder named `"AC/DC"`. What should I do?

```
Dir.mkdir("AC/DC")
```

will give an error message like this

```
in `mkdir': No such file or directory @ dir_s_mkdir - AC/DC (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Comment: I don't think that is allowed at the OS level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create directories recursively in ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686032/how-to-create-directories-recursively-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using an alternative UNICODE character instead of a standard forward slash?

Perhaps you could use:

'FULLWIDTH SOLIDUS' (U+FF0F)
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff0f/index.htm

```
Dir.mkdir("AC／DC")
```

or

'DIVISION SLASH' (U+2215)
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2215/index.htm

```
Dir.mkdir("AC∕DC")
```

Comment: Thanks! Problem Solved!